# Putty not connecting to server

Tags: putty

I try to connect my server with putty. It throws **Network error: Connection timed out**. Is there any special server settings I need to do before try with putty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify which port the server is listening for Putty on.

Then, make sure this port is open on your router (if you are not in the same network as the SSH server).

If you have both of these set correctly, and you can connect to the SSH server inside the network - it is likely that the outside network you are on is blocking the traffic.

**Edit**

You can use nmap to check which ports a computer is listening on:

```
nmap <serverAddress>
```

will give you a result like this:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
5900/tcp open  vnc
```

Comment: I have not much knowledge about the server. Kindly let me know how I check/change the port

Comment: I got the following error when trying to use nmap: 'nmap' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to install it. If it's Debian based you can just `sudo apt-get install nmap`